# AngularJs: how to integrate ui.comments module?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to integrate angular ui.comments module in my website but I don't know how it works. I read the [doc](http://caitp.github.io/ui-comments/docs/#/api) but I have no ideas because of my weak understanding of english(I used google translate to write this question).

can someone help me with a full example ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Download the script (@ https://github.com/caitp/ui-comments).

Include it in your index.html (using `<script...>`).

Inject the module into your angular app.
E.g: `angular.module("myApp", ['ui.comments'])`